# Setting AppWidget's title using data encoded as JSON

Tags: android, json, widget

I'm working with json. I parsed the JSON and I can show my JSON (images and text) on ListView. Now I want to show JSON's first item's title in my widget.

I successfully created the widget but I have a problem with the JSON's first item's title.

This is a my code:

```
public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static String CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE = "CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE";
RemoteViews views;
int appWidgetId;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onReceiver()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent, 0);

        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_demo);
        String aa = (MainActivity.itemList.get(0)
                .get(MainActivity.KEY_title)).toString();
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetPic, pendingIntent);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetTitle, pendingIntent);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetDesc, pendingIntent);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetDesc, aa);
        views.setImageViewBitmap(
                R.id.widgetPic,
                ((BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.background)).getBitmap());

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}

public void updateAppWidget(Context context,
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
    RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_demo);
    try {

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
}

}
```

BaseAdapter.java code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

private int screenSize;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d,
        int screenSize) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.data = d;
    this.screenSize = screenSize;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView journal = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.smalljournal);
    TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.smalltitle);
    TextView description = (TextView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.smallDescription);
    ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.smallthumb);
    TextView statId = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.smallstatID);
    TextView DateTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.smallDateTime);
    HashMap<String, String> itemList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    itemList = data.get(position);

    journal.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_journal));
    statId.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_statID));
    journal.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);

    String titleString = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_title);

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    // coming date : 2014-02-03T18:45:00
    String DateTimeTxt = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate).replace(
            "T", " ");
    // DateTimeTxt = date;
    try {
        Date _d = df.parse(DateTimeTxt);
        SimpleDateFormat new_df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        String _s = new_df.format(_d);
        DateTime.setText(_s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL)
        description.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    else
        description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    title.setText(titleString);
    title.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);
    description.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_description));
    description.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);

    String url = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_image);
    // url = url.replace("-c.jpg", ".jpg");

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, thumb_image);

    return vi;
}

}
```

MainActivity.java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public String URL = "********************";

public static String KEY_title = "title";
public static String KEY_description = "description";
public static String KEY_image = "image";
public static String KEY_journal = "journal";
public static String KEY_JournalID = "JournalID";
public static String KEY_pubDate = "pubDate";
public static String KEY_statID = "statID";
public JSONArray jsonarray;
public ListView list;
public JSONParser jsonparser;
static MyAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog pDialog, pDialog1;
static String fontPath2 = "font.ttf";
public static Typeface tf2;
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
public ImageLoader imageLoader;
static final int DIALOG_ERROR_CONNECTION = 1;

public static String dateTime;
private ArrayList<Content> contents = new ArrayList<Content>();
public ImageView image;
public EditText searchInput;
public LinearLayout mainLayout, SlideLayout;

public TransparentProgressDialog pd;

public Tools tools;

public static boolean CheckListview = true;
private int screenSize;
int windowWidth;

public LoadDataAllChanelsToServer loadData;

public TextView journal, tittle, description, smalllink, DateTime,
        smallstatID;
private ConnectionDetector cd;
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
Writer writer;
public File yourFile;
View menu_Slide;

@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
    SlideLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SlideLayout);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemList, screenSize);

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnCaughtException(this,
            this));
    loadData = new LoadDataAllChanelsToServer();

    menu_Slide = (findViewById(R.id.menu_button));

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    searchInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_search_query);
    tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath2);

    pd = new TransparentProgressDialog(this, R.drawable.loader);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            journal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.smalljournal);

            tittle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.smalltitle);
            description = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.smallDescription);
            smalllink = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.smalllink);
            DateTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.smallDateTime);
            smallstatID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.smallstatID);
            String Stringjournal = journal.getText().toString();
            String Stringtittle = tittle.getText().toString();
            String Stringdescription = description.getText().toString();
            String Stringlink = smalllink.getText().toString();
            String StringdateTime = DateTime.getText().toString();
            String StringstatID = smallstatID.getText().toString();
            HideKeyBoadr();
            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
            in.putExtra("KEY_journal", Stringjournal);
            in.putExtra("KEY_title", Stringtittle);
            in.putExtra("KEY_description", Stringdescription);
            in.putExtra("KEY_link", Stringlink);
            in.putExtra("KEY_pubDate", StringdateTime);
            in.putExtra("KEY_statID", StringstatID);

            String url = itemList.get(position).get(MainActivity.KEY_image);
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                in.putExtra("Bitmap", url);
            }

            else {
                if (url.endsWith("-c.jpg"))
                    url = url.replace("-c.jpg", ".jpg");
                in.putExtra("Bitmap", url);
            }

            in.putExtra("Bitmap", url);

            startActivity(in);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_left_in,
                    R.anim.trans_left_out);

        }
    });

    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

        return;
    } else {

        loadData.execute();

    }

}

public void HideKeyBoadr() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchInput.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

private class LoadDataAllChanelsToServer extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        jsonparser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonparser.getJSONfromURL(URL);
        try {

            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("journal", jsonobject.getString(KEY_journal));
                map.put("image", jsonobject.getString(KEY_image));
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString(KEY_title));
                map.put("description",
                        jsonobject.getString(KEY_description));
                map.put("JournalID", jsonobject.getString(KEY_JournalID));
                map.put("pubDate", jsonobject.getString(KEY_pubDate));
                map.put("statID", jsonobject.getString(KEY_statID));

                Content cont = new Content(jsonobject.getString("journal"),
                        jsonobject.getString("image"),
                        jsonobject.getString("title"),
                        jsonobject.getString("pubDate"),
                        jsonobject.getString("description"),
                        jsonobject.getString("JournalID"),
                        jsonobject.getString("statID"));
                contents.add(cont);

                itemList.add(map);
                dateTime = itemList.get(itemList.size() - 1).get(
                        KEY_pubDate);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return itemList.toString();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            if (pd != null) {
                pd.dismiss();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        try {
            adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemList, screenSize);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    createDialog();

}

private void createDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDlg.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");

    alertDlg.setCancelable(false);

    alertDlg.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();

                }

            }

    );

    alertDlg.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }

    });

    alertDlg.create().show();
}

}
```

My problem is: When I click the widget I get

> indexofboundexception (invalid index 0,size 1)

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is: When I click the widget I get
>
> indexofboundexception (invalid index 0,size 1)
>
> What is the problem?

That is too much code to look at. Please narrow your issue down and show the exact point the issue is occurring at.

Use your debugger to step through your code. 1st, identify the exact line at which the issue is occurring. Next, use your debugger to inspect the variables at that point. The error is an index out of bounds, so you're accessing a point in a list that is bigger than the size of the list.